# How to check the type of variable that would store a given value (contained in a String)?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans

How Can I check the Type of a variable . in this way :

Pseudo Code :

```
do{
     VARIABLE =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"X = ");

}while(VARIABLE != Integer);

Set_X(VARIABLE);
```

Comment: You declared the variable, you already know its declared type.

Comment: What you want to do is try parsing the value returned by `showInputDialog` into an `Integer`. Those are all keywords, look them up.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I believe the OP wrongly assumed there would be an auto-conversion from string to numeric. He/she wants to check for whether the string is a valid integer/double/etc/

Comment: how about the getClass() method?

Comment: @hexafraction Yeah. The point I was trying to make is that you have to use the jargon correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, your `VARIABLE` variable will be of type `String`.

You can try/catch `Integer.valueOf` on that variable to get its `Integer` value.

If a `NumberFormatException` is thrown, it means the user input cannot be converted to `Integer`.

For instance (draft code):

```
// initializing Integer interpretation
Integer input = null;
// infinite loop - breaks only once user has entered a valid integer-parseable value
while (true) {
    // trying to convert user input after showing option pane
    try {
        input = Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "X = "));
        // breaking infinite loop
        break;
    }
    // conversion unsuccessful
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        // TODO handle any error message if you need to
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't check it for *any* type, obviously. You can, however, try to parse it using parsers of known types and, if parsing succeeds for one, cast it to that type and move on.

For example, the integer-parsing helper function is `Integer.parseInt(String)`. Unfortunately, it throws an exception on failure (which will make your code ugly and slow at that point) and I'm not sure there are alternatives in the base library (equivalent to, say, C#'s `TryParse`).

Answer (score 0):

The following example uses a Class object to print the class name of an object:

```
void printClassName(Object obj) {
         System.out.println("The class of " + obj +
                            " is " + obj.getClass().getName());
     }
```

Hence this code will perform the check you require:

```
do{
    VARIABLE =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"X = ").getClass().getName();

    }while(!(VARIABLE.equals("java.lang.Integer"));
```